# Read apk permissions at installation time

Tags: android, permissions, android-manifest, apk

I'm making an application that will detect malware applications.
I have make it for now to read the permissions of all install applications.
Now i want to make it read permissions when you are going to install an apk like the system do which see a list with the permission needed by the app.
Any ideas?

Comment: Install the apk from your application?

Comment: @WangYun but i want to read the permissions before i install it

Answer (score 1):

Your app can't hook into the install process initiated by another app. You could offer your own install method which first does the desired checks before initiating the install via the system. However, this does not prevent a user from installing an app via another way, e.g., the Play Store app.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you means installing apk from your application.
   You can Parse The APK file's AndroidManifest.xml first.
   A simple to do this is referring to the android installer source code.
   Core class:
   [frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageParser.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/content/pm/PackageParser.java)
   refer to **parsePackageLite  parsePermission**  function
2. If you means hook the apk installing out of your application.
   It is very difficult, Although we can hook into the system install process with root permission. I have not try this way by far.

May this helps.